# Make NUnit fail on invalid test parameters

Tags: c#, nunit

Say that we have the following unit test:

```
[Test]
public void OneAndOneTest(int one)
{
   Assert.That(1 + one, Is.EqualTo(2));
}
```

The compiler will accept this code. But the test itself is incorrect as it should have been `[TestCase(1)]` instead of `[test]`. When running this test specifically with Nunit, it will give an error saying there is a parameter mismatch. However, when I run all test in a solution, I get a 'skipped' result instead of the said error.

Locally this is an annoyance. But you should have tested your test when writing them, so it's not too big of an issue. *(should is the keyword here...)*

However, when Jenkins runs said to test it should always fail. Failing the build on skipped tests is not an option as the place I work at allows for skipped tests in some cases.

The problems are with Nunit (I think). Both my local system and Jenkins run the NUnit executable and interpenetrate the output from the executable. My local system ports it into Dot cover while Jenkins has it dumped into an XML file that the `Nunit plugin` analyses later on in the build process.

Long story short: **Is there, with Nunit, a way to fail the build when running all test in a solution with one or more tests having an incorrect amount of parameters**

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using? I've tried the same thing with NUnit 3.6 and test and overall result are "Failed"... Could that be an issue with older versions of NUnit?

Comment: Test is invalid and should give an error rather than a failure. Overall result should be failed. It should not be skipped except in a very early version of NUnit that considered invalid tests as skipped. To give a real answer would require knowing the versions of the framework and runner involved.

Comment: Good point on the version. When checking I noticed we are running a surprisingly old version (2.6.4). I'll update it later today and see if that helps.

Comment: The old version of Nunit was the problem. Pulled the newest version of Nunit from nuget and the above test case works as I would have expected. @Charlie if you could post it as a answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy it helped... even as a comment. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with NUnit version, I've tried the exact same thing with latest version (NUnit 3.6) and the test result as well as the overall result is "Failed", see output below from NUnit Console:

**NUnit Console Runner 3.6.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Charlie Poole
Errors, Failures and Warnings**

1) Invalid : ConsoleApplication1.Program.add
Method has non-void return value, but no result is expected
Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 1, Passed: 0, Failed: 1, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
    Failed Tests - Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Invalid: 1